# How to manage requests without get parameters

Tags: java, servlets

I am currently using front controller pattern in a Java servlet and and redirecting requests to an appropriate handler via a "action" GET parameter. So, every link or process in the application will route to the front controller with an appropriate `?action=x` query string and then the front controller uses the output from `request.getParameter("action")` to load and execute the appropriate handler.

How can I do this without having query strings in all of my URLs on the web application?

Comment: You will need to parse the URL and decide what to do based on that information.

Comment: If you wanted to hide your params you could use request.getRequestDispatcher(urlWithParams).forward(request, response); So your params would be hidden in url, but they would exist anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the general approach used by most of the HTTP services framework.
You can use two things to decide about the handlers mapping:

1. The reference URL of entity i.e. URL part appended to the base URL of your application
2. The Http method, if you want to have different handlers for different HTTP operations

For example, you have this URL

http://mydomain.com/myapplication/myentity

Here the base URL part is: http://mydomain.com/myapplication/

Entity reference URL part is: myentity

Also the operation can be mapped to the HTTP method : GET(get), POST(create), DELETE(remove), PUT(update)

So you should have mapping of refURL `myentity` to some handler like `MyEntityHandler` class alongwith the operartion(optional). Pass the input request and response object for necessary information to the handler class.